# C# : Method name expected

Tags: c#, multithreading, methods

I have that method that counts files in a certain folder:

```
    private void countfiles(string path)
    {
        if (path != "")
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);

            foreach (FileInfo filesindires in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                if (filesindires.FullName != Application.ExecutablePath)
                {
                    num_files++;
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                }
            }

            foreach (DirectoryInfo dirsinfolder in dir.GetDirectories())
            {
                countfiles(dirsinfolder.FullName);
            }
        }           
    }
```

and when the user clicks on the count button I wanted to make a thread, so the program doesn't hang.

```
Thread count = new Thread(new ThreadStart(countfiles(@"E:/test")));
```

But I get this error even before debugging:

```
Method Name Expected
```

I dont understand; what does that error need from me?

Finally thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's

```
Thread count = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(countfiles));    
count.Start(@"E:/test");
```

You don't have to pass the parameters, just the method name.

Also you will need to change the type of the parameter to `object`, not `string`. Alternatively, if you want to keep the `string` parameter, you can use:

```
Thread count = new Thread(
   o => 
   {
       countFiles((string)o);    
   });
count.Start(@"E:/test");
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is here:

```
new ThreadStart(countfiles(@"E:/test"))
```

The argument is a *method-call* trying to masquerade as a *method-group*. The compiler can turn a compatible method-group, lambda expression or anonymous method to a delegate-type but not a method call.

Try one of these :

```
// Lambda
var thread = new Thread(() => countfiles(@"E:/test")); 

// Anonymous method
var thread = new Thread( delegate() { countfiles(@"E:/test"); });
```

If you want to use a method-group, you'll need a separate method:

```
private void CountTestFiles()
{
     countFiles(@"E:/test");
}
```

and then you can do:

```
// Method-group
var thread = new Thread(CountTestFiles)
```

You could also work with the `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegate-type and the associated overloads of the `Thread` constructor, but it's a little awkward to work with since the argument is `object`, so a cast somewhere or the other will be unavoidable.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegate. This will pass the values for you.

```
Thread count = new Thread(countfiles); 
count.Start(@"E:/test");
```

Answer (score 1):

The ThreadStart constructor is expected your code to look like:

```
Thread count = new Thread(new ThreadStart(countfiles));
count.Start();
```

It needs to know which method to execute, not the result of the method. But since you have a parameter, you need to do it like this:

```
Thread count = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(countFiles));
count.Start(@"E:/test");
```